# How to invoke and accept OTP using google2fa-laravel package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am using [google2fa-laravel](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/google2fa-laravel) package to enable OTP verification for my users on registration and login. The documentation describes how I can register 2fa secrets for users in the registration path, however what it doesn't describe well it how to enable verification on login for users.

I understand there is a `2fa` [middleware route](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/google2fa-laravel#middleware) which can be added to push users to a particular view set in the `google2fa.php` configuration file, but thats about it.

I have created my own view that corresponds to `google2fa.php` as follows:

```
'view' => 'auth.otp'
```

My auth/otop.blade.php

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('verify') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="form-group">
        <p>Please enter the one time password generated on your Google Authenticator App. <br> Ensure you submit the current one because it refreshes every 30 seconds.</p>
        <label for="one_time_password" class="col-md-4 control-label">One Time Password</label>

        <input id="one_time_password" type="number" class="form-control col-md-6" name="one_time_password" required autofocus>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Verify</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

You can see I have pointed to a route called `verify` in my but this really doesn't lead anywhere, the [documentation](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/google2fa-laravel#configuring-the-view) points to `/google2fa/authenticate` but this route isn't defined by the package and isn't mentioned anywhere else so does nothing and leads to a 404.

I have created a route called `verify` which runs a method that runs the following:

```
public function verifySession(Request $request)
{
    $google2fa = app('pragmarx.google2fa');

    $secret = $request->input('one_time_password');

    $valid = $google2fa->verifyKey(auth()->user()->google2fa_secret, $secret);

    Log::debug($valid);

}
```

I got information on how to verify the key using the source package [google2fa](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/google2fa), while my code die validate the code I'm not sure what do to next, if I go back to the route I originally clicked on with the `2fa` middleware, it hasn't registered that I have verified myself and redirects me to the OTP page again.

Would appreciate some guidance on how I can resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this which basically just redirects to the homepage (logged in) if $valid, and if not, it will return the origin index view to re-enter the otp (assuming they entered it wrong in someway). Hope this helps!

```
$valid = $google2fa->verifyKey($request->google2fa_secret, $request->one_time_password);
        if ($valid) {

           $request->session()->put('login', 1);
           return redirect(route('home'));
        
        } else {
           
            return view('google2fa.index', ['show_QR' => false, 'QR_Image' => '', 'secret' => '');
       }
```

Comment: I know this is an old post but does this solution work? I had the same problem as the OP as the OTP was verified but it wouldn't redirect to the home page as it could not "pass" the 2fa middleware i specified for the homepage. Not sure what is the fix.

I tried your solution but it is the same issue as well.

Comment: I used this solution for an older version of my company’s site but it worked just fine. It was an older version of laravel though, can’t remember which one at the moment.

Comment: I see. I still couldn't find a solution as after I verify successfully, it just keep redirecting me to the 2fa page as if it couldn't pass the 2fa middleware.